# is it possible to implement moveable Toolbar with Ext.js, if yes, how to do that with my code?

Tags: javascript, extjs, toolbar

it is my toolbar which i want to move free in any position of my desktop.
what i need to change for it? maybe xtype'toolbar' or different extend'Ext.panel.Panel'??

```
Ext.define('test.view.desktop.Toolbar', {
    bodyStyle: "background: #CAE1FF; border: 4px solid red;",
    width: 500,
    height: 200,
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    title: 'test',

    alias: "widget.testtoolbarX",
    requires: [
    "Ext.form.FieldSet"
    ],
    dockedItems: [
     {

         xtype: 'toolbar',
         dock: 'top',
         items: [
          {

              xtype: 'tbtext',
              text: '<b style="font-size: 20px; margin-left: 300px; color: red;">I am Toolbar</b>',

          },
          {
              xtype: 'tbfill',



          },

           {
               text: 'Report',
               menu: {
                   items: [
                       {
                           text: 'Export'
                           ,
                           menu: {
                               items: [
                                   {
                                       text: 'PDF'

                                   }, {
                                       text: 'Excel'
                                   }
                                   , {
                                       text: 'CSV'
                                   }
                               ]
                           }

                       }, {
                           text: 'Filter'
                       }
                   ]
               }
           },
            {
                xtype: 'cycle',

                text: 'File',
                menu: {
                    xtype: 'menu',
                    width: 120,
                    items: [

                     {
                         text: 'Upload'
                     },
                     {
                         text: 'Share'
                     },
                     {
                         text: 'Popout'
                     }
                    ]
                }
            },
          {
              xtype: 'button',
              text: 'Help',
              url: 'http://test/faq.html',
              //baseParams: {
              //    q: 'html+anchor+tag'
              //},
              tooltip: 'Get the answers to frequently asked questions about'
          }
          ,
          //{
          //    xtype: 'htmleditor',
          //    text: 'Help'
          //}

         ]
     }
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a window with a fixed width and add a toolbar to it.
Kyle Fransham pointed this out but I'll show it with a code snippet:

```
Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
    layout: 'fit',
    width   : 500,
    dockedItems: {
        xtype: 'toolbar',
        items: [{
                text: 'Button'
            },
            '->',
            {
                xtype    : 'textfield',
                name     : 'field1',
                emptyText: 'enter search term'
            },              
            '-','text 1', 
            { xtype: 'tbspacer' },
            'text 2'
        ]
    }
}).show();
```

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to accomplish this is to:

1. Add the toolbar to a panel, and the panel to a window.
2. Play with the size of the window so that only the toolbar can be seen.
3. In the window's config, add `headerPosition: 'right'` to move the titlebar/header off to the right of the window.

Now you have a toolbar that can be dragged anywhere on your desktop by the handle on the right  (the titlebar of the window.)

Comment: what is a window exactly`? i'm working just with panel and desktop

Comment: A window is just another Ext class.  It behaves like you'd expect, for a window.  Doc is here:  http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.window.Window